# How to properly hover circles in a data layer

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to highlight all shapes inside of a data layer.

Currently to hover over circles requires setting an icon for the marker.

```
this.setStyle({
    icon: { //circles
        strokeColor: rand_colors[color_index + 3],
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        scale: 7.5,
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
    }, //polygons
    strokeColor: rand_colors[color_index + 2],
    fillColor: rand_colors[color_index + 3],
    strokeWeight: 1
});
```

The issue is the icon has a "scale" attribute which changes according to zoom. How can I make this scale stick to the circles radius?

Here's what I have so far and a working example to see that it works--the icon is just not very noticeable with the circles.

[Working fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/dizzled/pyv03m59/)

```js
let map;
let rand_colors = ["#ff0000",
    "#ff9900",
    "#ccff00",
    "#cc00ff",
    "#ff0099"
]

function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 10,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(33.619003, -83.867405),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        zoomControl: true
    });
    let bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    // Same color hover together
    let circleLayer = new google.maps.Data();
    circleLayer.addListener('addfeature', function(e) {
        e.feature.getGeometry().forEachLatLng(function(latlng) {
            bounds.extend(latlng);
        });
    });

    circleLayer.setStyle(function(feature) {
        var geo = feature.getGeometry();
        if (geo.getType().toLowerCase() === 'point') {
            // replace point with a circle
            let circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                map: map,
                center: feature.getGeometry().get(),
                radius: parseFloat(feature.getProperty("radius")),
                fillColor: '#f00',
                fillOpacity: 0.5,
                strokeWeight: 0,
            });
            bounds.union(circle.getBounds());
            //hide the marker
            return {
                icon: {
                    strokeColor: "#000",
                    path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                    scale: 7.5,
                    anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
                }
            };
        } else {
            return {
                strokeColor: rand_colors[2],
                fillColor: rand_colors[3],
                strokeWeight: 1
            };
        }
    });

    circleLayer.addGeoJson(map_data);
    circleLayer.setMap(map);
    addMapHoverListener(circleLayer, 0, 1);

    map.fitBounds(bounds);

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
}

function addMapHoverListener(layer, color_index) {
    google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'mouseover', function(event) {
        console.log(event.feature.getGeometry().getType());
        this.setStyle({
            icon: {
                strokeColor: rand_colors[color_index+1],
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                scale: 7.5,
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
            },
            strokeColor: rand_colors[color_index],
            fillColor: rand_colors[color_index + 1],
            strokeWeight: 1
        });

    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'mouseout', function(event) {
        console.log("Hover out function");
        this.setStyle({
            icon: {
                strokeColor: rand_colors[color_index + 3],
                path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                scale: 7.5,
                anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 0)
            },
            strokeColor: rand_colors[color_index + 2],
            fillColor: rand_colors[color_index + 3],
            strokeWeight: 1
        });
    });
}

let map_data = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "radius": 75000
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -116.806640625,
                    41.934976500546604
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "radius": 125000
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [
                    -117.93273925781249,
                    43.71950494269107
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {},
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [
                    [
                        [
                            -124.244384765625,
                            42.00032514831621
                        ],
                        [
                            -123.98071289062499,
                            41.87774145109676
                        ],
                        [
                            -118.10302734374999,
                            45.26715476332791
                        ],
                        [
                            -119.69604492187499,
                            45.84410779560204
                        ],
                        [
                            -122.75024414062499,
                            45.42158812329091
                        ],
                        [
                            -123.96972656249999,
                            46.31658418182218
                        ],
                        [
                            -124.617919921875,
                            42.89206418807337
                        ],
                        [
                            -124.244384765625,
                            42.00032514831621
                        ]
                    ]
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
};
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
#map {
  height: 400px;
}

/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Hover Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKEY&callback=initMap&libraries=drawing&v=weekly" async></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *Currently to hover over circles requires setting an icon for the marker* - Why would it require an icon / a marker? What do you mean?

Comment: @MrUpsidown loading data from geojson there is no circles so you take your "Point" and turn it into a circle. After doing so this circle is now inside of the map but not inside of the data layer loaded from the geojson. The only thing remaining is the "Marker/Point" which is then displayed as an icon. This icon is the only part of the data layer that seems to respond to my event listeners.

Comment: Are you going to have multiple *layers* (`google.maps.Data()`)? If yes, then you *could* define an id for each layer, set that same id for each Circle related to that layer, add each Circle to an array, then in your mouseover/out listeners, loop through the circles array and modify the `fillColor` if the current Circle has the same id.

Comment: Quick demo: https://jsfiddle.net/upsidown/59nuv03t/ - See the changes on lines 9, 24, 43, and from lines 89 to 97, and the same block in the other listener.

Comment: @MrUpsidown this is actually what I was looking for! I didn't know you can set id's for objects. Thank you MrUpsidedown if you'd like to get the answer I can mark you if you post :)

Comment: I removed the API key from your code, please don't share API keys on public websites for security purposes.